# Pipe a file on a Unix server to the client

Tags: unix, pipe, putty

I'm using PuTTY to connect to a zOS mainframe (running USS, IBM's Unix-compatible software) and I'd like to download a hex dump (using od) of a file without making a copy of it on the filesystem. Is there a way that I can save or pipe stdout (through PuTTY) directly to a file on my (Windows XP) client?

Comment: is it possible to create a pipe over the internet? i thought that's why sockets were created. why not use ftp/sftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure session logging for your PuTTY session, as [per the documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-logging).  Then just run `od` on the server, wait until it finishes, and then close your log file.  You'll need to trim the cruft at the beginning and end (because it has your whole session), but you should end up with what you want.

Note that upon inspection that documentation link may be for an older version of PuTTY, so YMMV but I'm sure that more recent versions also support session logging.

If you were to install a command-line ssh tool (e.g., running OpenSSH under Cygwin), you could then do the standard "ssh hostname command > file" sort of redirection.